# Docker Volumes in Production - Wordpress as an example

Tags: wordpress, docker, volumes

This question doesn't have to be specific to Wordpress but I think it's a good example to understand concepts in a production website.

I'm trying to understand the correct way to use Docker Volumes in production.
I'll discuss 3 areas to understand the best practise and if possible best performance.

**Database**
If I create a named volume for the database I can expose a port to have access to the database. This would give the best performance and convenience for myself. For security I change the port to 127.0.0.1:xxxx to make it inaccessible from outside the server.

**wp-content/themes**
I will manage this directory and any changes I make to the site would come from my child theme.
If I store this inside a volume it's difficult for me to upload changes but most guides recommend not using bind mounts for production environments.

**wp-content/uploads**
This is a directory managed completely by the web server. If I used a volume for the whole web server file system then uploading a new volume would overwrite the uploads directory and I'd lose any changes made by the web server.

As I said this isn't specific to Worpdress and any CMS system could be used as an example. The main question is how to deal with Docker in production when you have directories you want to manage and directories the web server should manage?

Comment: What do you mean by "uploading a new volume"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the main point here: containers are ephemeral by nature.
Any data that should outlive the container **should be in a volume** regardless of the application usage or responsibility of management (be it the server or the sysadmin).

In the example you're bringing, uploads and themes (or the entire wp-content for that matter) are supposed to be volumes and the person who provisioned them should also populate their contents, be it by bootstrapping the application using a second container or simply by copying the data to the volume before the container starts.

As for the database, containers don't need to be bound to the host machine's network to be used. They can join a private network and keep all the communication between each other in there, without any need to be exposed (which can be as safe as binding it to 127.0.0.1). For more info on that, check [docker network docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and a few orchestration tools (docker-compose, kubernetes, etc).

tl;dr use volumes as much as you need to keep non-ephemeral data alive in between containers. They're the only tool you've got to keep your data intact in case your container goes bye-bye.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to expand I'm talking about how you maintain the site and not just how it's created at the start.
If I want to make changes to the themes directory on a live site how would I do that in a volume without wiping out anything uploaded in the uploads directory?

Comment: I'm not sure to follow. You can set different volumes to different directories and interact with both independently. Also you don't need to recreate the volume in order to change its contents (so I don't see why the uploads directory would be wiped).